# Force tmux to only take one keystroke

Tags: terminal, tmux

Frequently, using tmux I'll want to switch panes and then immediately give input. For example I'll jump over `(C-B->)`, then want to run the last command `(^-Enter)`. However, it appears there's a timeout where I'm still in command mode.

Can I force tmux to only interpret a single keystroke in command mode `(C-B)` and then immediately give control back to the terminal? I feel like this is annoying and gets in my way more than it is a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
set -s escape-time 0
```

This means that tmux will not wait any amount of time for a keystroke combination (it will still wait indefinitely following `<prefix>` for a tmux command)